# How lens for specs are manufactured for a given power? Do thickness, refractive index play role?

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses

I read some where that if the prescribed glass power is more, glass must be made of higher refractive index to lessen the thickness. But from knowledge of physics, power just depends on focal length(curvature of the lens and not on refractive index, thickness). How far am I Correct?

And my glass power is -3.5 D in both eyes. My glass being concave lens (I guess it from power) and not being in cuboid shape (two prisms bonded together analogy) why don't it disperse white light?

Comment: It does disperse colors.  Your prescription is a bit weak to be able to observe.  I would suggest that some simple reading up on how a lens works would be helpful.

Comment: Something to think about: what if the lens had the exact same index of refraction as air?

Comment: Refer lens makers formula. Assuming refractive index of air is 1, if lens also has refractive index 1, then the light won't get focused. Or in other words focal length is infinity.  If lens has same refractive index as air, you can imagine the system as air cut off in the shape of glass which actually makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Refractive power is determined by (a) the material chosen, which gives the index of refraction, and (b) the surface curvature, which tells how parallel rays will be brought together -- the focal plane.

In the past there were limited choices for glass, and so the curvature was the main parameter. For convenience of fit, the front surface is convex, and the rear surface is concave, which reduces the refractive power for a given index of refraction; if this design cannot give sufficient refractive power, they make the glass thicker to support more curvature.

With graduated optics they use materials with graded index of refraction, which in theory can produce flat optical devices.

Here is an elementary introduction: https://optics.synopsys.com/learn/learn-intro-optics-design.html

Comment: I can elaborate more; negative lenses actually defocus the light. Chromatic aberrations are too slight to notice with ordinary glasses, and can be corrected by using two types of glass.

Comment: I wouldn't say that negative power defocusses, rather that it creates a virtual focal point.   More to the point:  it's the combination of the human eye's lens power and the eyeglass lens power that defines the ultimate real image location.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: you are correct; I was thinking about when you hold the glasses over a piece of paper, with a beam of light passing through them ... but I didn't bother to actually say this!